# Calling Google Custom Search overlay from text link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, google-custom-search

I'm using the newish style of Google Custom Search that overlays your search results over your current page.

The code below creates a search box that calls the overlay. I'm wondering if there's anyway to create a text link that would also launch the results of the overlay as some of our articles have a line like "You can always search for more references on [person] on our site." The older two page CSE ethod allowed us to call a results page with /search.shtml?q=person

```
<script>
(function() {    
var cx = 'myCSEidnumber';
var gcse = document.createElement('script');
gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
gcse.async = true;
gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);    
})();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

I created a text link like this: `/currentpage?cx=myCSEidnumber&amp;q=$mysearchterms`

Clicking on that link doesn't create the results overlay. If I copy that link and re-enter it in the browser it does pop up the overlay.

I've searched the Google CSE site and forums but can't seem to find anything. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the cx param in your url, only the q param. However, you do need the  element present in your link target page for the overlay to show up. The element will render both overlay AND search box, but you can hide the searchbox with css, e.g.:

```
.gsc-search-box {
    display:none;
}
```

Here's an example (although jsfiddle will not render css for you, you need to add it on your page separately):

http://jsfiddle.net/RDHS4/3/

Answer (score 0):

Your HREF should be set using this `/?q=$mysearchterms`

Example: To display result on the index page or any other page:

```
href="http://www.your-web-site.com/?q=$mysearchterms"
```

```
href="http://www.your-web-site.com/search/?q=$mysearchterms"
```

```
href="http://www.your-web-site.com/result.php?q=$mysearchterms"
```

Then you can go ahead to hide the input field using css.

```
.gsc-search-box { display:none; }
```